# Authenticate S3 request using Authorization header

Tags: bash, rest, amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-s3

I would like to authenticate my S3 requests using this [method](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RESTAuthentication.html#ConstructingTheAuthenticationHeader). For this purpose I have adapted scripts presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658147/download-private-file-from-s3-using-bash). Here is how it looks like:

```
#!/bin/sh
file="$2"
bucket="$1"
resource="/${bucket}/${file}"
contentType="$3"
dateValue="`date +'%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z'`"
stringToSign="GET\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${resource}"
s3Key="$AWS_ACCESS_KEY"
s3Secret="$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY"
signature=`/bin/echo -en "$stringToSign" | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`
curl -v -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" -H "Date: ${dateValue}" -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3Key}:${signature}" https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file}
```

My file permissions are like this:

[image]

and file content type is:

[image]

Here is how do I call my script:

```
./getfile1.sh tmp666 7b5879dd9b894f7fc5a14b895f01abd1.png image/png
```

Unfortunately I am getting `SignatureDoesNotMatch` error although `StringToSign` returned by AWS is matching mine:

```
<StringToSign>GET

image/png
Wed, 28 Sep 2016 12:46:14 +0200
/tmp666/7b5879dd9b894f7fc5a14b895f01abd1.png</StringToSign>
```

My IAM user has admin permissions. What am I doing wrong? I have spent half of day trying to solve it and feel powerless.

Comment: Well, here's what it isn't: it isn't anything other than a problem with your code.  That is, it's not a permissions issue because that will never cause this error.  Why are you sending `Content-Type: image/png`?  That header, in a request, indicates the content you are *sending*. With a `GET` request, you aren't sending content. That isn't quite right, but should technically work. Does the date in your calculated string to sign precisely match what S3 returns in the error, down to the last byte?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot without `Content-Type` it is the same error. Date I am sending and date returned in the error are exactly the same.

Comment: Give this a try http://stackoverflow.com/a/40835539/977939