# What does the following shell script line mean?

Tags: shell, amazon-s3

[Link to stack overflow page describing s3 curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658147/download-private-file-from-s3-using-bash)

I am new to shell scripting and I need to understand the meaning of the following line:

```
signature=`/bin/echo -n "$stringToSign" | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary | base64`
```

1. Does it mean that output of `/bin/echo -n "$stringToSign"` is piped to `openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary`
2. What does `/bin/echo -n` mean ?
3. What is a simple explanation of `openssl sha1 -hmac` ?
4. What is `openssl sha1 -hmac` doing to "$stringToSign" piped into it ? Is it encrypting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes
2. `-n :    do not output the trailing newline` [1](https://linux.die.net/man/1/echo)
3. `sha1 refers to SHA-1 message disgest algorithm` [2](https://linux.die.net/man/1/openssl)
4. `-hmac is the message authentication code` [3](https://linux.die.net/man/3/hmac)
5. Yes. If you have a linux box, you can execute `openssl sha1 -h`, you will find the following line: 
    `-hmac key       create hashed MAC with key`

It creates a hash using your provided key. Here is a simple cmdline example.

```
$ echo -n "SomeStuff" | openssl sha1 -hmac key
(stdin)= c127d9119057757c0de8a1e081c1327c489c0eaa
```

and with binary

```
$ echo -n "SomeStuff" | openssl sha1 -hmac key -binary
�����2|H��
```

You can store the binary in `.hmac` file. You can then use software like, hmaccalc that provides [sha1hmac](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sha1hmac) to decrypt the stored binary key for your use case.

For more info. Read the manual in the attached links.

Comment: Thanks can you please help me out with my 4th question

Answer (score 1):

Basicaly it used to calculates a signature based on the SHA1 algorithm (openssl command part) and insure this does contains only ASCII chars (base64 command part). the answers of @iamauser are corrects for the low level explanation.

ex:

```
 ~ export stringToSign='This a sample string that i do want to sign !!!'
 ~ signature=`/bin/echo -n "$stringToSign" | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3Secret} -binary |      base64`
 ~ echo $signature
ZTRhYWVhMTZkYzZlZDZjNjJhNjMzNzliYTAyNTFkYzUxYjI5YWYwYQo=
```