# Can i download a file from a private bucket using wget or curl? I have only access and secret key credentials

Tags: amazon-s3, curl, wget

I have a private bucket that has a single zip file, a need to download it but i can't use aws cli or aws cmd. Can i do it using wget ou curl?

Comment: It can't be done with purl wget or curl commands.  If you can use openssl as well, [you can sign the request yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27658147/download-private-file-from-s3-using-bash).

Answer (score 4):

I managed to do this with this script. If you call it `download.sh` assuming you have a bucket called `my-bucket` and a file in it called `file.zip`, and your aws key environment variables set, you should be able to download the file by calling.

`./download.sh file.zip my-bucket`

I adapted this from a similar script to upload a file I found [here](https://www.gyanblog.com/aws/how-upload-aws-s3-curl/)

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Download a file from s3 without any 3rd party tools
# thanks https://www.gyanblog.com/aws/how-upload-aws-s3-curl/

file_path=$1
bucket=$2
set -eu pipefail
# about the file
filepath="/${bucket}/${file_path}"

# metadata
contentType="application/octet-stream"
dateValue=`date -R`
signature_string="GET\n\n${contentType}\n${dateValue}\n${filepath}"

#s3 keys
s3_access_key=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
s3_secret_key=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

#prepare signature hash to be sent in Authorization header
signature_hash=`echo -en ${signature_string} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${s3_secret_key} -binary | base64`

# actual curl command to do PUT operation on s3
curl -sSo ${file_path} \
  -H "Host: ${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com" \
  -H "Date: ${dateValue}" \
  -H "Content-Type: ${contentType}" \
  -H "Authorization: AWS ${s3_access_key}:${signature_hash}" \
  https://${bucket}.s3.amazonaws.com/${file_path}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in theory you can make a HTTP request using the [Amazon S3 REST API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/Welcome.html) but for that to work you need to authenticate correctly which you can do for example with a Authentication Header which you must then pass to `curl` or `wget`.

The problem is though that you need to write code to create those valid signatures you need to provide in the Authentication Header so it might be a bit of a hassle.

Comment: What do you think about using pre-sign URL? Is this a good option?

Comment: If you already have a URL with correctly signed authorization parameters that works available than sure why not use it. But I doubt that you have that as the authorization token you need is only valid for a limited amount of time so you will have to create a token again sooner or later.